# How convert Point on Curve into AES key?

Tags: aes, elliptic-curves

I'm playing around with ECC, trying to encrypt traffic between my webapp and backend (its not a product, im trying to learn and understand more about ECC)

I managed to generate keys, successful run key exchange and got same point on both ends.

Now I wonder how I should convert my point which has 2 coordinates into AES key.

Comment: Are you using [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) for key exchange? Not a clear question.

Comment: [SEC1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#page=62) codifies ECDH, and uses a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function).

Comment: @kelalaka i did ECDH, i multiply alices public key(which i haf as point) by bobs private key (and vice versa) and i got shared point on curve. now my question is, how i should convert tuple (x,y) into 256bit  key.

Comment: KDF's as fgrieu pointed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most symmetric cryptographic algorithms requires a key that is indistinguishable from random. This means that the process used to generate the key must have a uniform, independent distribution over all bit-strings of the appropriate length. Using a non-uniformly-random key not only reduces the brute force needed to guess it, but may also open the door to [related-key attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Related-key_attack).

The expressions “key agreement” and “key exchange” are often used to mean a mechanism like (elliptic curve) Diffie-Hellman, but (EC)DH itself does not produce a key, it only produces a shared secret. This secret is in some numerical range that depends on the curve: not all $2^n$-bit values are possible. Even within this range, it is not uniformly distributed (it can't be since there isn't the same number of private points and public coordinates).

To go from the shared secret to a key, you need to use a **[key derivation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function)**. A KDF takes a secret which has a cryptographically high number of possible values but may not be uniformly distributed, and has output that is indistinguishable from random to anyone who doesn't know the secret.

In a pinch, if you only need one symmetric key from the key exchange, hashing the shared secret with a cryptographic hash such as SHA-256 or SHA-512 is fine. If you need more key material than one hash's length, or if you prefer to use a standard construction that may be more robust in case a partial weakness is discovered in a hash function, there are (too) many standardized key derivation functions, for example [HKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) (robust and popular), the [TLS 1.2 PRF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-5) (a variant of HKDF which is specific to TLS), the [NIST SP 800-56C key derivation functions](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-56c/rev-2/draft) (some hash-based like HKDF, some AES-based), etc.